# Search column of a dataframe with each i in another column of the same dataframe - R

Tags: r

I have a df that has duplicates, but it is not clear they are duplicates, as the strings are not identical.

For example: `Company X | 123` is the same as `Company XXXy | 123/1234` as they contain the same numerical ID `123`

I have a column of just the numerical ids, `TendererID`. I want to search through a column of strings `TendererEN` to see if the id is contained in the name. I want to generate a count that adds a `1` to the column `dummy` if `TendererID` is in the string name `TendererEN`, and create a variable `temp1` that pastes the id that the string contained.

For example, here is a for loop that works and does what I'd like it to do. But for my dataset (300 k observations) it is extremely slow. Any ideas about how to do this more efficiently would be much appreciated

```
TendererEN <- c("KHARKIV RESEARCH INSTITUTE OF FORENSIC EXPERTISE THEM. HONORED. PROF. M. S. BOKARIUS of the MINISTRY of justice of UKRAINE | 00015622", "РАХУНКОВА ПАЛАТА | 00013540
", "МОЗ України | 00012925", "| 00012925", "x00012925")
TendererID <- c(00012925, 00013540, 160, 200000,365)
test <- data.frame(TendererEN, TendererID)
test$dummy<-0
test$temp1<-""

for(i in test$TendererID) {
  test<-mutate(test, dummy=ifelse(grepl(i, test$TendererEN), dummy+1, dummy),
  temp1=ifelse(grepl(i, test$TendererEN), paste0(temp1, i), temp1))
}
```

Comment: apologies, sloppy copy/paste

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `str_count` to count number of times `TendererID` is present in `TendererEN` field and `str_extract_all` to extract all the values.

```
library(tidyverse)

pattern <- str_c(test$TendererID, collapse = '|')

test %>% 
  mutate(dummy = str_count(TendererEN, pattern), 
         temp1 = map_chr(str_extract_all(TendererEN, pattern), toString))
```

Comment: Awesome, this worked, much faster than my attempt, thank  you!